# Cant find the values I stored into a map

Tags: c++

I'm basically reading a file character by character, and when I encounter a new number I store it in a `std::map` as a key with the element equal to 1. The more times I encounter the same number, I increment that key's element:

```
if(intMap.count(singleCharacter)){
    //keyexist  just increment count else
    //cout<<"exist"<<endl;
                
    int newValue =  intMap.at(singleCharacter) + 1; //grabs the value that already exists and we need to incrmenet it by 1 and store the new value in the map.

    std::map<int, int>::iterator it = intMap.find(singleCharacter); //finds the single character and increments it by 1.

    if (it != intMap.end())
        it->second = newValue; //setting the new increment value into the element
}else{
    //doesnt exist and and we need to create it and incrmenet by 1
    //cout<<"doesnt exist"<<endl;
    intMap.insert(pair<int, int>(singleCharacter,1));
    cout<<singleCharacter <<" new made : "<<intMap.at(singleCharacter) <<endl;
    }
}

for (auto& p : intMap ) {
    cout << p.first<<": "<< p.second <<endl;; // "Karl", "George"
}
```

The only problem is, when I try to print out all of the values in the map, it gives me random numbers, and I don't understand where they are coming from.

This the file that I'm reading:

```
An International Standard Book Number (ISBN) is a code of 10 characters, referred to as ISBN-10,                                                                             
 separated by dashes such as 0-7637-0798-8. An ISBN-10 consists of four parts: a group code, a publisher code,                                                                
 a code that uniquely identifies the book among those published by a particular publisher, and a check character.                                                             
 The check character is used to validate an ISBN. For the ISBN 0-7637-0798-8, the group code is 0,                                                                            
 which identifies the book as one from an English-speaking country. The publisher code 7637 is for "Jones and Bartlett Publishers
```

The output I'm getting:

```
48: 8                                                                                                                                                                          
49: 3                                                                                                                                                                          
51: 3                                                                                                                                                                          
54: 3                                                                                                                                                                          
55: 8                                                                                                                                                                          
56: 4                                                                                                                                                                          
57: 2
```

The output I should be getting should be like:

```
1: and the amount of times it was seen
```

That goes the same for any number.

Comment: What does it print? Provide a sample output to help us understand what you see

Comment: I think you need to improve the example code as it seems to be not complete and also show some output.

Comment: Maybe `singleCharacter` is corrupt or does not  have the values you expect.

Comment: I think all of this code could be replaced with `intMap[singleCharacter]++;` I guess except for the cout.

Comment: Wow 3 lookups and 50 lines of code instead of one lookup and one line, amazing!

Comment: @RayRay [can't reproduce](https://ideone.com/Rh9JvC). And as others have said, that entire `if/else` block can be [reduced to a single statement](https://ideone.com/eQeFfG): `intMap[singleCharacter]++;` The [`map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) inserts a new default-initialized element if the requested key does not exist yet.

Comment: I updated it to show more Information but wait I can just use intmap[singlecharacter]++ to increment the value???

Comment: @RayRay yes `std::map::operator[]` is precisely designed for such case and code sample for its documetation clearly shows that https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: @RayRay you did not show the code that is reading the file and parsing numbers from it.  But `48`, `49`, `51`, ... those look like ASCII codes for **characters** `'0'`, `'1'`, `'2'`, ....  Which means you are not actually *converting* those characters into integers `0`, `1`, `2`, ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get those "random" numbers because you are using `std::map<int,int>` instead of `std::map<char,int>`. What you get printed are the ASCII numeric codes for character symbols, and their counts.

So, you need to either change the map's type, or cast the keys back to `char`:

```
for (auto& p : intMap ) {
    cout << static_cast<char>(p.first) << ": "<< p.second <<endl;
}
```

Note: `std::map::operator[]` is precisely designed for such case, it will initialize missed values with 0 in this case, so all of your conditions can be replaced with:

```
intMap[singleCharacter]++;
```

Details can be found in [this documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at).

Comment: my eye  is twitching right now  im new to c++ and maps I wrote a over engineered bunch of code which literally couldve been done   in one line

Comment: @RayRay Be careful. The behavior of operator[] is different for maps than it is for vectors. For vectors and other containers it does not extend the size of the vector if your index is out of range.

Comment: @drescherjm actually there is another container that does it - `std::unordered_map`. So there 2 containers that do and there are 2 that do not (`std::vector` and `std::deque`). There is `std::array` which is quite different as it does not change size at all so your generalization "other containers" is quite confusing.

Comment: I considered `std::unordered_map` to be included in the word maps. Sorry to be confusing.

Comment: @drescherjm it's ok, I just wanted to clarify so OP would not be confused even more.